# How to get text from the DOM element in cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, gettext

I am new in cypress, I want to create a dynamic method that returns the text of whatever DOM element pass on it, so I have created one but it returns some unexpected result please see the below code and suggest to me where I am doing wrong or what is the best option for achieving this task.

**login_objrepo.json**

```
{
  "Signin_lbl":".login100-form-title.p-b-10"  //Locator
}
```

**Login.sepc.js**

```
import commonUtility from "../../support/commonUtility";
const util = new commonUtility();
const objLogin = require('../../fixtures/login_objrepo');

    describe('Login Page', function () {
        it('Verify Page', () => {
            util.openUrl(objLogin.URL);
            const exp = 'Sign In';
            const act = util.getText(objLogin.Signin_lbl);
            cy.log("Exp title=" + exp + " and Act=" + act)
            cy.get(objLogin.Signin_lbl).should('have.text',exp);
        })
    })
```

**commonUtility.js**

```
 class commonUtility
    {
     getText(locator)
        {
            cy.wait(3000);
            
            cy.get(locator).then(($attribute)=> {
                let txt=$attribute.text();
                cy.log("Retun Text is = "+ txt);
            })
            return this;
        }
    }
```

`here (txt variable) got the valid text but, in the above file(Login.sepc.js) were to call it there showing ([object Object])... how to get the same here also?`

==========================
**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of logging the element in this case? If the test failed, it would output what the Actual found was, as well as the Expected.

Comment: @agoff,  here my purpose is I want to get this text in the login.spec.js file to print and other processes on this return text. 
in short, this is a common method so whenever we want to get the text from the appropriate elements and after that, some process/operation on it then will do it

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.then()` to extract the text value from the returned `[object Object]`,

```js
class commonUtility {

  getText(locator) {
    return cy.get(locator).then(($element) => {   // return cy.get not "this"
      let txt = $element.text();
      return txt                                  // in here, return txt
    })
  }
}
```

```js
describe('Login Page', function () {
  it('Verify Page', () => {
    util.openUrl(objLogin.URL);

    const exp = 'Sign In';

    util.getText(objLogin.Signin_lbl).then((act) => {  // extract txt from [object Object]
      console.log("Exp title=" + exp + " and Act=" + act)
    })

    cy.get(objLogin.Signin_lbl).should('have.text', exp);
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this code is working fine on my side,  just one modifying the required. like where we call this method like "act" there need to write something like that "act.text()"

Comment: this is not getting as my expected can you provide more easily like I want to store this text in VARIABLE, can we do that, because I had tried but not working, simple my concern is I have EXP result and i want to store another ACT result into a variable then after as per requirement, i can you use it.

Comment: also, is there any alternative if we pass just the locator and appropriate methods/functions will return its text?. here we already created functions in "commonUtility.js" but their side does not return direct text. here again, we need to write some extra code to receive this text, is there any simple way to retrieve those "txt" values on another page where we called out